# Using expire_page on Heroku Cedar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, heroku

Has anyone managed to use expire_page with Heroku on the Cedar stack? I have a back and forth with support that has been unproductive. From my testing, it works with a single dyno but when you have multiple dynos, only one expires the page. So, it will serve the old page sometimes. I know Varnish was an option in previous stacks but what is the HTTP cache solution for Cedar? Right now I am just using expire_action with memcached but this is not as good because it still hits the Rails stack.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Rack::Cache is the answer. You can use the Last Modified to expire pages using headers. I will probably use this in addition to expire_action. Here is the tutorial on it:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-static-assets-rails31

It is not perfect because I think the request will still queue but it is better than nothing.